# Как заменить один символ в sql таблице?

Tags: запрос, sql

Нужен запрос, чтобы например заменить в одном поле все встречающиеся буквы С, например, на П. Как это сделать?

Comment: Неплохо было бы в вопросе указать используемую СУБД. Обратите внимание, что ответили вам по MySql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Функция [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
UPDATE `users` SET `firstname` = REPLACE( `firstname`, 'С', 'П');
```